Fluid Dynamics - Lid driven cavity flow- why is only the first row updated, while I iterate over all grid cells?
I have to simulate a lid driven cavity flow. The idea is as follows:

Initialize boundary conditions
Update stream function (using discretized version, update only if the convergence condition is satisfied)
Update vorticity boundary conditions (using discretized version)
Update vorticity interior (using discretized version)
Loop over step 2-4

The grids are updated using the SOR algorithm.
Later on, I need to obtain the velocity and pressure fields. But in order to do this, I need to have this part working first.
I have been working on this for quite some days now, and the grid only keeps updating the first row. I tried a lot of bug fixing and did solve some issues, but this one remains.
What am I overlooking?
Here is my script so far, I am trying for small values of N and tmax.
EDIT: Implemented errors from comment below. Streamfunction is now being updated, but the vorticity doesn't seem to update properly on the interior.
Wrongly updated vorticity, lid is on left side of graph.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

def Lid_Driven_Cavity_Flow(N, u, w, omega, dt, V_lid, Re):
    """ 
    Function to run simulation of lid driven cavity flow
    """
    h=1/N

    def BC_streamfunction():
        """
        Impose boundary conditions on streamfunction
        """
        u[0,:] = V_lid   #lid
        u[1:,N-1] = 0    #right wall
        u[1:,0] = 0      #left wall
        u[N-1,1:N] = 0   #bottom
    
    def BC_vorticity():
        """
        Impose boundary conditions on vorticity
        """
        w[0,:] = (2/h**2) * (u[0,:] - u[1,:]) + (2/h) * V_lid    #lid
        w[1:,N-1] = (2/h**2) * (u[1:N,N-1] - u[1:N,N-2])         #right wall
        w[1:,0] = (2/h**2) * (u[1:N,0] - u[1:N,1])               #left wall
        w[N-1,1:N] = (2/h**2) * (u[N-1,1:N] - u[N-2,1:N])        #bottom
    
    def Update_Streamfunction():   
        """
        This function updates the streamfunction on the interior
        """     
        while True:
            u_prev = copy.deepcopy(u)
            for i in range(1,N-1):     #columns
                for j in range(1,N-1): #rows
                    #print("coordinates are", j, i)
                    r1 = (1/4 * (w[j,i]*h**2 + u[j,i+1] + u[j,i-1] +           \
                          u[j+1,i] + u[j-1,i])) - u_prev[j,i]
                    u[j,i] += omega * r1
                    #print(r1)
                    #print(u)
        
            if np.max(((1/N**2)*np.abs(u_prev - u))) < 10e-6: #Convergence check
                break

    def Update_Vorticity_Interior():
        """
        This function updates the vorticity field on the interior
        """
        while True: 
            w_prev = copy.deepcopy(w)
            for i in range(1,N-1): #N-2 is on the wall, but range doesn't 
                                   #include N-1
                for j in range(1,N-1):
                    a = (-1)/(4*h**2) * (u[j+1,i] - u[j-1,i]) * (w[j,i+1] -    \
                         w[j,i-1])
                    b = (1/4*h**2) * (u[j,i+1] - u[j,i-1]) * (w[j+1,i] -       \
                         w[j-1,i])
                    c = (1/Re*h**2) * (u[j,i+1] - 4*u[j,i] + u[j,i-1] +        \
                         u[j+1,i] + u[j-1,i])

                    r2 = omega * dt * (a + b + c) - w_prev[j,i]

                    w[j,i] += r2

            if np.max(((1/N**2)*np.abs(w_prev - w))) < 10e-6: #Convergence check
                break
    
    """
    Below, there is a while loop that iterates over a number of timesteps.
    First the boundary conditions on the streamfunction and vorticity are 
    intialized. 
    Then for each timestep the streamfunction is updated, then the boundary
    conditions on the interior are updated and lastly the vorticity interior 
    is updated. Then the loop starts over again. 
    """
    t = 0
    tmax = 10
    steps = int(tmax/dt)
    BC_streamfunction()
    #print("After running BC_streamfunction, the matrices are \n", u,"\n", w)
    BC_vorticity()
    #print("After running BC_vorticity, the matrices are \n", u,"\n", w)
    while t < steps:
       t += 1
       Update_Streamfunction()
       #print("After running Update_Streamfunction, the matrices are \n", u, "\n", w)
       BC_vorticity()
       #print("After running BC_vorticity, the matrices are \n", u,"\n", w)
       Update_Vorticity_Interior()
       #print("After running Update_Vorticity_Interior, the matrices are \n", u,"\n", w)

    def Velocity(): 
        """
        Calculate velocity in x- and y-direction, and use the length of the 
        tangent vector as value for the velocity on a grid point.
        """
        v = np.zeros([N,N])
        for i in range(0,N-1):
            for j in range(0,N-1):
                v_y = (-1) * (u[j,i+1] + u[j,i-1]) / (2*h)
                v_x = (u[j+1,i] - u[j-1,i]) / (2*h)
                v[j,i] = np.sqrt(v_y**2+v_x**2)
        return v
    
    def ContourPlot(matrix, title, xtitle, ytitle, number_levels):
        """
        This funciton produces a contourplot. 
        """
        x = range(0,N)
        y = range(0,N)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        Z = matrix[X,Y]

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=number_levels)
        ax.set_title(title)
        ax.set_xlabel(xtitle)
        ax.set_ylabel(ytitle)

    ContourPlot(u, 'Streamfunction', 'j-direction', 'i-direction', 100)
    ContourPlot(w, 'Vorticity', 'j-direction', 'i-direction', 100)
    ContourPlot(Velocity(), 'Velocityfield', 'j-direction', 'i-direction', 100)

    def Pressure():
        """
        Here, the pressure will be calculated.
        Still working on this function.
        """
        return 0

Lid_Driven_Cavity_Flow(10, np.zeros([10,10]), np.zeros([10,10]), 0.25, 0.01, 1, 100)


I think that if you post this sort of question on StackOverflow then it is only fair to tell people what equations you are solving: in this case a streamfunction / vorticity formulation (in non-dimensional form):

Here, you would extract the velocity field from

Unfortunately, you use u in your code for the streamfunction, where most of the rest of the world would use greek letter psi.
You have several programming errors.
b = (1/4*h**2) is bracketed wrongly, so that you end up multiplying by h2 rather than dividing by it. Similarly, variable c.
In your vorticity equation you are failing to distinguish between the value of vorticity at the last timestep (which is nowhere in your code) and the last iteration within a timestep.
You have a major physical error in your boundary conditions. The upper boundary condition on velocity should be set via the vorticity and NOT via the streamfunction. The whole of the boundary is a streamline, irrespective of whether some of it is moving or not, so simply take the streamfunction as 0 there. If you discretise things correctly then suitable boundary conditions can be written

Finally, if you want the moving lid to be at the top of your plots then you need to associate it with the correct indices. To coincide with your plots I have reversed your i,j indexing to the more common "i increasing in direction of x, j increasing in direction of y" form. The lid is then at the maximum j index.
You can try the following, but please don't make this thread a succession of debugging corrections. I've reduced the Reynolds number to make it more interesting.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Lid_Driven_Cavity_Flow(N, u, w, omega, dt, V_lid, Re):
    h=1/N

    def BC_streamfunction():
        u[0,:] = u[N-1,:] = u[:,0] = u[:,N-1] = 0
    
    def BC_vorticity():
        w[:,N-1] = (2/h**2) * ( u[:,N-1] - u[:,N-2] ) - (2/h) * V_lid
        w[:  ,0] = (2/h**2) * ( u[:,0  ] - u[:,1  ] )
        w[0  ,:] = (2/h**2) * ( u[0  ,:] - u[1,:  ] )
        w[N-1,:] = (2/h**2) * ( u[N-1,:] - u[N-2,:] )
    
    def Update_Streamfunction():   
        while True:
            u_prev = u.copy()
            for i in range(1,N-1):
               for j in range(1,N-1):
                    r1 = 0.25 * ( w[i,j] * h**2 + u[i+1,j] + u[i-1,j] + u[i,j+1] + u[i,j-1] ) - u_prev[i,j]
                    u[i,j] += omega * r1
        
            if np.max(((1/N**2)*np.abs(u_prev - u))) < 10e-6: break

    def Update_Vorticity_Interior():
        w_old = w.copy()
        while True: 
            w_prev = w.copy()
            for i in range(1,N-1):
                for j in range(1,N-1):
                    a = (-1)/( 4*h**2) * (u[i,j+1] - u[i,j-1]) * (w[i+1,j] - w[i-1,j])
                    b =   1 /( 4*h**2) * (u[i+1,j] - u[i-1,j]) * (w[i,j+1] - w[i,j-1])
                    c =   1 /(Re*h**2) * (w[i+1,j] + w[i-1,j] - 4*w[i,j] + w[i,j+1] + w[i,j-1])
                    r2 = dt * (a + b + c) + w_old[i,j] - w_prev[i,j]
                    w[i,j] += omega * r2

            if np.max(((1/N**2)*np.abs(w_prev - w))) < 10e-6: break
    
    def ContourPlot(matrix, title):
        x = range(N)
        y = range(N)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        CS = ax.contour( matrix[X,Y] )
        ax.set_title(title)
        plt.show()

    def Velocity():
        v_x = np.zeros( (N,N) )
        v_y = np.zeros( (N,N) )
        for i in range(1,N-1):
            for j in range(1,N-1):
                v_x[i,j] = (u[i,j+1] - u[i,j-1]) / (2*h)
                v_y[i,j] =-(u[i+1,j] - u[i-1,j]) / (2*h)
        v_x[1:N-1,N-1] = V_lid

        x = range(N)
        y = range(N)
        X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.quiver(v_x[X,Y],v_y[X,Y],pivot='middle')
        plt.show()


    t = 0
    tmax = 10
    steps = int(tmax/dt)
    BC_streamfunction()
    BC_vorticity()
    while t < steps:
       t += 1
       Update_Streamfunction()
       Update_Vorticity_Interior()
       BC_vorticity()

    ContourPlot(u, 'Streamfunction' )
    ContourPlot(w, 'Vorticity' )
    Velocity()


N = 20
Lid_Driven_Cavity_Flow(N, np.zeros([N,N]), np.zeros([N,N]), 0.25, 0.01, 1, 10 )

Some output:


