Vorticity Function Yielding Peculiar Result
I am working with a lid-driven cavity flow problem, using the discretised versions of the vorticity Navier-Stokes equations:

For some reason, my stream function seems to be working (I believe so, at least), but my vorticity plots are a bit strange I think. I switched some things around based on suggestions, and now I have an... interesting result.
The full code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Initialising Parameters:
N = 50
L = 1.0
Re = 5
dt = 0.0001
Vwall = 1.0
h = L/(N-1)


#Initialising Arrays:
u = np.zeros((N, N))
w = np.zeros((N,N))
Vx = np.zeros((N, N))
Vy = np.zeros((N, N))
P = np.zeros((N, N))

#Setting Boundary Conditions (Velocity):
Vx[:, 0] = 0  #Left wall
Vx[:, -1] = 0  #Right wall
Vx[0, :] = 0  #Bottom wall
Vx[-1, :] = 1  #Top wall

Vy[:, 0] = 0  #Left wall
Vy[:, -1] = 0  #Right wall
Vy[0, :] = 0  #Bottom wall
Vy[-1, :] = 0  #Top wall


#Update stream function using 1a (Using SOR):
def updateStreamfn(u, w, h, tolerance=1e-6, maxIter=1000, omega=1.3):
  #SOR for solving Poisson Equation (iterating using while & for loops):
  maxDiff = tolerance + 1
  iter = 0

  #New while loop replacing for loop:
  while maxDiff > tolerance and iter < maxIter:
    uOld = np.copy(u)

    for i in range(1, u.shape[0] - 1):
      for j in range(1, u.shape[1] - 1):

        #Update Equation (using discretised 1a):
        u[i, j] = (1-omega) * u[i, j] + (omega * 0.25) *(
            u[i+1, j] + u[i-1, j] + u[i, j+1] + u[i, j-1] + (h**2 * w[i, j])
            )
      
      #Break at convergence after maximum difference value reached:
    maxDiff = np.max(np.abs(u - uOld))
    iter += 1
    
    if iter >= maxIter:
      print("Reached max iterations without convergence.")
      break

  return u


#Update vorticity on wall with eqn 10 for all boundaries:
def updateWallVorticity(w, u, Vwall, h):
  N = w.shape[0]
  
  #Top wall (y=max at moving lid)
  for i in range(N):
    w[i, 0] = -((2 / h**2) * (u[i, 1] - u[i, 0]) + (2 * Vwall / h))

  #Bottom wall (y=0)
  for i in range(N):
    w[i, N-1] = -((2 / h**2) * (u[i, N-2] - u[i, N-1]))

  #Left wall (x=0)
  for j in range(N):
    w[0, j] = -((2 / h**2) * (u[1, j] - u[0, j]))

  #Right wall (x=max)
  for j in range(N):
    w[N-1, j] = -((2 / h**2) * (u[N-2, j] - u[N-1, j]))


#Update vorticity in interior with 1b:
def updateInteriorVorticity(w, u, dt, Re, h, tolerance=1e-6, maxIter=1000, omega=1.3):
  wNew = np.copy(w)
  maxDiff = tolerance + 1
  iter_count = 0

  while maxDiff > tolerance and iter_count < maxIter:
    wOld = np.copy(wNew)
    
    #For loop to update through iterations:
    for i in range(1, w.shape[0] - 1):
      for j in range(1, w.shape[1] - 1):
        
        #Advection and diffusion terms:
        advectionx = ((u[i, j+1] - u[i, j-1]) / (2 * h) * ((w[i+1, j] - w[i-1, j]) / (2 * h)))
        advectiony = ((u[i+1, j] - u[i-1, j]) / (2 * h)) * ((w[i, j+1] - w[i, j-1]) / (2 * h))
        
        diffusion = (1 / Re) * ((w[i+1, j] - (2 * w[i, j]) + w[i-1, j]) / h**2 + (
            w[i, j+1] - (2 * w[i, j]) + w[i, j-1]) / h**2)
        
        #Update formula:
        wNew[i, j] = (1 - omega) * w[i, j] + omega * (w[i, j] + dt * (-advectionx + advectiony + diffusion))
        
    #Convergence check
    maxDiff = np.max(np.abs(wNew - wOld))
    iter_count += 1

    if iter_count >= maxIter:
      print("Vorticity update reached max iterations without full convergence.")
      break
  
    return wNew


#Task 4 plots:
def plotStreamfnFin(u, Vx, Vy, title="Stream Function (u)", time_step=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.contourf(u, levels=50, cmap='viridis')
    plt.colorbar(label='Stream Function Value')

    #Plotting time steps:
    if time_step is not None:
        plt.title(f"{title} at Time Step {time_step}")
    else:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("Grid X")
    plt.ylabel("Grid Y")
    
    #Streamlines to indicate flow direction:
    Y, X = np.mgrid[0:u.shape[0], 0:u.shape[1]]
    plt.streamplot(X, Y, Vx, Vy, color='white', linewidth=0.5)
    plt.show()

def plotStreamfnInt(u, title="Stream Function (u)", time_step=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.contourf(u, levels=50, cmap='viridis')
    plt.colorbar(label='Stream Function Value')

    #Plotting time steps:
    if time_step is not None:
        plt.title(f"{title} at Time Step {time_step}")
    else:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("Grid X")
    plt.ylabel("Grid Y")


#Vorticity plot:
def plotVorticity(w, title="Vorticity (w)", time_step=None):
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    contour = plt.contourf(w, levels=50, cmap='viridis')
    plt.colorbar(contour, label='Vorticity Value')
    
    #Overlay contour lines:
    plt.contour(w, levels=10, colors='white', linewidths=0.5, linestyles='solid')
    
    #Title and labels:
    if time_step is not None:
        plt.title(f"{title} at Time Step {time_step}")
    else:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("Grid X")
    plt.ylabel("Grid Y")
    plt.show()


#Main time-stepping loop:
numTimesteps = 100
visualInter = 10

for n in range(numTimesteps):
    #Update stream function:
    u = updateStreamfn(u, w, h)
    
    #Update vorticity on boundaries:
    updateWallVorticity(w, u, Vwall, h)

    #Update vorticity in interior:
    w = updateInteriorVorticity(w, u, dt, Re, h)
    
    if n % visualInter == 0:
      print(f"Time Step: {n}")

      #Plotting stream function with streamlines:
      plotStreamfnInt(u, title=f"Stream Function (u)", time_step=n)

      #Plotting the vorticity:
      plotVorticity(w, title=f"Vorticity (w)", time_step=n)
    

#Calculating Vx and Vy:
      Vx[1:-1, 1:-1] = (u[1:-1, 2:] - u[1:-1, :-2]) / (2 * h)
      Vy[1:-1, 1:-1] = -(u[2:, 1:-1] - u[:-2, 1:-1]) / (2 * h)  
  
#Plotting the results at the final timestep
plotStreamfnFin(u, Vx, Vy, title="Final Stream Function (u)")
plotVorticity(w, title="Final Vorticity (w)")

Now my final plots (stream and vorticity) look like:


I am honestly not sure what's going on with the vorticity plot. It's still not looking... as expected for vorticity? Am I wrong?

You have mathematical errors. Your coded boundary conditions are wrong: they should all have a minus sign in front. You are not either timestepping the vorticity equation, nor iterating to convergence within a timestep. You probably need to under-relax, rather than over-relax, coupled equations (take omega = 0.5, say). You should converge the vorticity equation in the same way that you do the streamfunction equation. Your classmate is obviously doing the same problem: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79151088/fluid-dynamics-lid-driven-cavity-flow-why-is-only-the-first-row-updated-whil

Oh my gods, DUH, yes, I see it now! The vorticity is written as -w!! I finally see something!! Also, I am fiddling with omega and Re now, and I can actually se the stream function change. I am not entirely sure if the new vorticity plot actually makes sense, though.
Are you saying I should apply the SOR method to the vorticity, too?
Also, a bunch of us have to do it, but I don't really know anyone in the class, lol.

I've changed it around, as you suggested. Do those look okay to you?

Your streamline picture doesn't look anything like that due to a moving lid (which should be basically rotational, not going through the sides). Your vorticity plot seems to suggest that you have two moving sides. I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Your main problems are that you are not timestepping the vorticity equation correctly and your x,y coordinates do not tally well with the traditional [i,j] matrix notation.
You will find it difficult to calculate the advection terms or the final velocity field, set the correct wall as a moving boundary or do the final plots unless you align your coordinates and indices something like the following:
y,j
^
|
|
|
+--------> x, i

You can choose to either update the vorticity equation explicity (forward-differencing) by setting maxIter=1 and omega=1 or, as it currently is, solve it by backward-differencing, with under-relaxed iteration within each timestep.
If you want to increase N then that will reduce the spatial step size and you may have to reduce dt to compensate.
I have simplified your plotting routines.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Initialising Parameters:
N = 50                       # number of nodes in each direction
L = 1.0                      # length of side
Re = 5                       # Reynolds number
dt = 0.0001                  # timestep
Vwall = 1.0                  # velocity (left-to-right) of top wall
h = L/(N-1)                  # spatial step size


#Initialising Arrays:
u  = np.zeros((N,N))
w  = np.zeros((N,N))
Vx = np.zeros((N,N));    Vx[:,-1] = Vwall        # Top wall
Vy = np.zeros((N,N))
p  = np.zeros((N,N))


# Update stream function
def updateStreamfn( u, w, h, tolerance=1e-6, maxIter=1000, omega=1.3 ):
    '''
    Solves streamfunction equation
       Laplacian(psi) = -w
    Uses SOR
    w is z component of vorticity (d.Vy/dx - d.Vx/dy)
    u is the streamfunction psi, defined such that
       Velocity_x = d(psi)/dy        Velocity_y = -d(psi)/dx
    '''
    maxDiff = tolerance + 1
    iter = 0

    while maxDiff > tolerance and iter < maxIter:
        uOld = np.copy(u)

        for i in range( 1, u.shape[0] - 1 ):
            for j in range( 1, u.shape[1] - 1):
                u[i,j] = (1-omega) * uOld[i,j] + omega * 0.25 * (u[i+1,j] + u[i-1,j] + u[i,j+1] + u[i,j-1] + h**2 * w[i, j] )
      
        maxDiff = np.max( np.abs( u - uOld ) )
        iter += 1
    
        if iter >= maxIter:
            print("Reached max iterations without convergence.")
            break

    return u



# Set vorticity boundary conditions
def updateWallVorticity( w, u, Vwall, h ):
    '''
    Updates vorticity boundary conditions
       w = (2/h^2)( psi(boundary) - psi(interior) ) - (2/h).Vtangential
    '''
    w[: ,-1] = (2/h**2) * ( u[: ,-1] - u[: ,-2] ) - (2/h) * Vwall
    w[: ,0 ] = (2/h**2) * ( u[: ,0 ] - u[: ,1 ] )
    w[0 ,: ] = (2/h**2) * ( u[0 ,: ] - u[1 ,: ] )
    w[-1,: ] = (2/h**2) * ( u[-1,: ] - u[-2,: ] )



# Update vorticity equation
def updateInteriorVorticity( w, u, dt, Re, h, tolerance=1e-6, maxIter=1000, omega=0.8 ):
    '''
    Updates time-dependent vorticity equation
        dw/dt + Vx.dw/dx + Vy.dw/dy = (1/Re)Laplacian(w)
    Either use:
    (1) Fully-explicit method (forward-Euler) by setting maxIter=1, omega=1; OR
    (2) Implicit iteration (backward-Euler) by Jacobi method with under-relaxation (omega <= 1)
    '''

    wPrev = np.copy(w)                 # value at end of last TIMESTEP
    maxDiff = tolerance + 1
    iter = 0

    while maxDiff > tolerance and iter < maxIter:
       wOld = np.copy(w)               # value at end of last ITERATION
    
       for i in range( 1, w.shape[0] - 1 ):
           for j in range( 1, w.shape[1] - 1 ):
               advectionx = ( u[i,j+1] - u[i,j-1] ) / (2 * h)   *   (wOld[i+1,j] - wOld[i-1,j]) / (2 * h)
               advectiony = ( u[i+1,j] - u[i-1,j] ) / (2 * h)   *   (wOld[i,j+1] - wOld[i,j-1]) / (2 * h)
               diffusion = 1/Re * ( wOld[i+1,j] + wOld[i-1,j] + wOld[i,j+1] + wOld[i,j-1] - 4*wOld[i,j] ) / h**2
               w[i,j] = (1-omega) * wOld[i,j]   +   omega * ( wPrev[i,j] + dt * ( -advectionx + advectiony + diffusion) )
        
       maxDiff = np.max(np.abs(w - wOld))
       iter += 1

       if iter >= maxIter > 1:
           print( "Vorticity update reached max iterations without full convergence." )
           break
  
    return w



def plotStreamfn( u, title="Stream Function (u)", time_step=None ):
    plt.figure( figsize=(8, 6) )
    x = np.linspace( 0, L, u.shape[0] )
    y = np.linspace( 0, L, u.shape[1] )
    Y, X = np.meshgrid( x, y )
    plt.contourf( X, Y, u, levels=20, cmap='viridis' )
    plt.colorbar( label='Stream Function Value' )
    plt.contour( X, Y, u, levels=10, colors='white', linewidths=1.0, linestyles='solid' )

    if time_step is not None:
        plt.title(f"{title} at Time Step {time_step}")
    else:
        plt.title(title)
        Vx[1:-1, 1:-1] =  ( u[ 1 : -1 , 2 :    ] - u[ 1: -1 ,   : -2 ] ) / (2 * h)    #  d(psi)/dy
        Vy[1:-1, 1:-1] = -( u[ 2 :    , 1 : -1 ] - u[  : -2 , 1 : -1 ] ) / (2 * h)    # -d(psi)/dx
        plt.quiver( X, Y, Vx, Vy )
    plt.show()



#Vorticity plot:
def plotVorticity( w, title="Vorticity (w)", time_step=None ):
    plt.figure( figsize=(8, 6) )
    x = np.linspace( 0, L, u.shape[0] )
    y = np.linspace( 0, L, u.shape[1] )
    Y, X = np.meshgrid( x, y )
    contour = plt.contourf( X, Y, w, levels=50, cmap='viridis' )
    plt.colorbar(contour, label='Vorticity Value')
    plt.contour( X, Y, w, levels=10, colors='white', linewidths=1.0, linestyles='solid' )
    
    if time_step is not None:
        plt.title(f"{title} at Time Step {time_step}")
    else:
        plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("Grid X")
    plt.ylabel("Grid Y")
    plt.show()


#Main time-stepping loop:
numTimesteps = 100
visualInter = 25

for n in range(numTimesteps):
    u = updateStreamfn(u, w, h)
    updateWallVorticity(w, u, Vwall, h)
    w = updateInteriorVorticity(w, u, dt, Re, h)
    
    if n % visualInter == 0:
       print(f"Time Step: {n}")
       plotStreamfn(u, title=f"Stream Function (u)", time_step=n)
       plotVorticity(w, title=f"Vorticity (w)", time_step=n)

plotStreamfn( u, title="Final Stream Function (u)" )
plotVorticity( w, title="Final Vorticity (w)" )




You are a true life saver. Thank you so much. Your explanations are very clear, and I fullly understand the changes. My TA was wondering why I added a convergence and SOR term to the vorticity function, but I don't see it working without it tbh. Cheers.

Well, it’s the difference between forward-Euler and backward-Euler timestepping. The latter is usually regarded as more stable. I've now amended the code so that you can do the vorticity equation without iteration if you wish (just set maxIter=1 and omega=1). I've also added further comments within the code.
